# jQuery plugin Flot crushes web site

Tags: jquery, flot

Using [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot) to show some graphs.
Out of the blue the website started to crush.
The problem is in this line at jquery.flot.js:

```
if (!c.getContext) // excanvas hack
    c = window.G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(c);
```

The exception: `G_vmlCanvasManager is undefined`.

Working well with Firefox 12 with the real web server.
Working well with Firefox 12 with Visual Studio 2010 (local server).
Working well when using IE 9 with the real web server.
Crushes when using IE 9 with Visual Studio 2010 (local server).
There is no IIS installed at the dev computer.

Re-installing VS and clearing its cache didn't helped.
Downloading fresh version of Flot didn't helped.
Disabling the authorization mechanism didn't helped.

Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Is there any difference in the content you are using between the dev machine and the "real web server"?

Comment: No, I've deleted the local version, download the server version and run it - works well in the server, crushes locally. Even reverting to an older version in the source control didn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates that the browser doesn't support HTML5 canvas, and you aren't using the Excanvas plugin to emulate it.

My guess is that the problem lies in your page not using the correct DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

When the DOCTYPE is missing or incorrect, IE9 renders the page in quirks mode, which does not support HTML5 canvas.  You're then either not including excanvas.js, or you have it wrapped in  an `[if lte IE 8]` conditional, which does not trigger, since the browser **is** IE9.

It's likely that your real web server automatically adds a DOCTYPE, while Visual Studio's doesn't.  If that's the case, then you need to either add it yourself, or cause the VS server to output one.

Comment: My deafult page has this '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'. Don't know if this is correct but it hasn't been changed for months.

Comment: Try the one from above, and verify that it's actually getting sent to the browser.

Comment: I did, same behavior. Something I've notice now (before the DOCTYPE change) - the page UI is not excally like it suppose to be. Do I have an authentication problem - the server cannot get CSS files nor JS?

Comment: We have progress! I've included excanvas.js and now I get no exception, but the UI is all messed up and Plot have axes but no graph...

Comment: In all Flot samples I've never seen anyone manually including this file. Flot has it in its own folder.

Comment: If you view source for any of Flot's examples, you'll see that they all include excanvas.js.  The fact that it works when you include excanvas.js implies that there is still some problem with your DOCTYPE, since IE9 normally does not require excanvas; only when rendering in quirks mode.

Comment: As for the other problems, those sound like issue with your site, unrelated to Flot or the current question.

Comment: thanks, I've change all my pages DOCTYPE to `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` and added this: `<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.Flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->`, still the Flot doesn't work well. How can I tell if the DOCTYPE is correct?

Comment: Load your page in IE9, then press F12 to bring up the developer tools pane.  At the top of the window, see what IE is using for 'browser mode' and 'document mode'.

Comment: Browser Mode: IE9 compat View, Document Mode: IE7 standards. When changing the Document Mode to IE9 everything is fine!! What does it means?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11343/discussion-between-dns-and-toy4fun)

Comment: I have reset my IE and everything is working well. I would like to thank you very much for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this function at the start encasing everything? :   $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: I'm using jquery.flot.js as-is. I do have my own script which uses this line and initializing the component. This works well until something happened – don't know what…

Comment: It's probably the canvas hack that's messing with the rendering.